# if else in php not working

Tags: php, html

I have a script in which there is if else statement in **PHP**. But it is not working.

Please help me out by finding my mistake.

```html
<?php
if(isset($POST['submit']))
{

    if(!empty($_POST['cno'])) 
    { 
        $cno = $_POST['cno'];
        echo $c_msg="2"; 
    }//end if
    else 
    { 
        echo $msg="1"; 
    }//end else

}//end if
?>
<?php
if(isset($msg))
{
 echo $msg;
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($c_msg))
{
 echo $c_msg;
}
?>
 <script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('cno').addEventListener('input', function() {
      document.getElementById('cnor').textContent = 'Track:- ' + this.value;
    });
  }
</script>
<div class="modal fade" id="track" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="trackLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="trackLabel">Track Your Shipment.</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="Track" action="" method="POST">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Enter Consignment Number</label>
                <input id="cno" name="cno" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Eg.:- JU05GHY1532"><button type="submit" id="cnor" name="cnor" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Track</button>
              </div>
            </div>

        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Please help me in finding my mistake from the above snippet.

I will be thankful for finding my mistakes.

Comment: use proper indentation and you should see the problem

Comment: everyone missed `$POST`

Comment: you should be getting a few notices for this.

Comment: There's also no submit bearing the `submit` name attribute.

Comment: @Fred-ii- there is submit in **button**

Comment: oh sure there is... for which POST array?

Comment: oops! I am unable to sort out!

Comment: `<button type="submit" id="cnor" name="cnor"` does not equal `$POST['submit']` and is failing for a few reasons.

Comment: `id="cnor"` is given so that I can have same value on button as textbox..

Comment: again; this condition `if(isset($POST['submit']))` will not happen.

Comment: so what should I do? I need error msg too and text on button

Comment: yoiu need to visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and set to catch and display and look at your developer console, should this also be JS-related; something to which I am not the guy for.

Comment: I also don't want to use **js** as it creates more problems when there is error

Comment: I have less time to go through the **PHP Manual** as I am just coding for society quiz which is to be handled tomorrow early morning (IST).

Answer (score 2):

Replace your PHP with the following to simplify matters:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    if(!empty($_POST['cno'])) 
    { 
        $cno = $_POST['cno'];
        echo $c_msg="2"; 
    }//end if
    else 
    { 
        echo $msg="1"; 
    }//end else

}//end if
?>
```

Comment: It didn't work.. I have edited the above snippet with your code.. but it didn't sort my problem

Comment: of course it didn't work. see comments up there

Comment: And so we did, amended. Thank to Fred for having an eye for detail!

Comment: @JulianKoster I didn't worked after update!!

Comment: @JulianKoster please sort it out

Answer (score 0):

As @Fred mentioned you have a typo: $_POST and not $POST for the first if

And You also miss a closing bracket:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //this is the wrong if condition
{
    $cno=$POST['cno'];
} //this is the missing closing bracket 
if(empty($cno))
{
```

Use an IDE with syntax highlighting and you can easilly see these errors

Comment: you should check my comments under their question.

Comment: you are right, didn't notice :)

Comment: there's a few more new comments too

Comment: I give up trying to fix all the typo ;)

Comment: there are far too many and if this is JS-related, I am so not the guy for it, which is why I didn't post an answer for it.